# Is there a module to convert Chinese character to Japanese (kanji) or Korean (hanja) in Python 3?

Tags: python, cjk

I'd like to switch CJK characters in Python 3.3. That is, I need to get 價(Korean) from  价(Chinese), and 価(Japanese) from 價. Is there a external module like that?

Comment: Is your character encoding [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)?

Answer (score 2):

### Unihan information

The [Unihan page about 價](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E5%83%B9) provide a simplified variant (vs. traditionnal), but doesn't seems to give Japanese/Korean one. So...

### CJKlib

I would recommend to have a look at [CJKlib](http://code.google.com/p/cjklib/), which has a feature section called [Variants](http://code.google.com/p/cjklib/wiki/Features#Variants) stating:

> Z-variant forms, which only differ in typeface

#### [update] Z-variant

Your sample character 價 (U+50F9) doesn't have a z-variant. However [価 (U+4FA1) has a kZVariant](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%E4%BE%A1) to U+50F9 價. This seems weird.

### Further reading

- Package documentation is available on [Python.org/pypi/cjklib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cjklib) ;
- [Z-variant form](http://www.definitions.net/definition/z-variant) definition.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.kishugiken.co.jp/cn/code10d.html) is a relatively complete conversion table. You can dump it to json for later use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import json


def gen(soup):
    for tr in soup.select('tr'):
        tds = tr.select('td.tdR4')
        if len(tds) == 6:
            yield tds[2].string, tds[3].string


uri = 'http://www.kishugiken.co.jp/cn/code10d.html'
soup = BS(requests.get(uri).content, 'html5lib')

d = {}
for hanzi, kanji in gen(soup):
    a = d.get(hanzi, [])
    a.append(kanji)
    d[hanzi] = a

print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

The code and it's output are in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Answeror/8183907).

Comment: Thanks for saving the gist, Answeror!  The original disappeared but your json persists!